# Remove the limit of number of parameters in CloudFormation stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

We have more than 60 parameters in our CF stack, which can't be listed. Is there a way to extend the limit without breaking the references(we have  nested stacks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than 60 parameters as per Cloudformation [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html)

> Maximum number of parameters that you can declare in your AWS CloudFormation template. 60 parameters. To specify more parameters, you can use mappings or lists in order to assign multiple values to a single parameter.